# OS related questions on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, declined-flags

I recently came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345348/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-pil-on-mac-snow-leopard-with-xcode-4-installed) question on SO and promptly flagged it as: `off topic; belongs on Super User`.

My flag was declined with the reason: `a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it`

Now understand that I'm not here to crib about my flag being declined, losing flag weight, etc. My question is: Am I wrong in considering that *off-topic*?

That question (to me) was about **installing** PIL on Snow Leapard and I thought [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) was the correct place for it.  If I'm wrong, I'd genuinely like to know so I can adapt my flagging practices accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the FAQ clearly states that Stack Overflow covers questions about:

> … software tools commonly used by programmers

As such, I would assume the **Python Imaging Library** is one of those tools. As the installation involves manually compiling from sources, setting some compiler flags, and generally has to do with Apple's developer suite Xcode, the question was fine for Stack Overflow all along.

Note however that it wouldn't have been completely off-topic for Super User. It's about installing computer software, and we probably wouldn't have closed it. But there's still a very strong programming background, hence (probably) your declined flag.

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 5):

There's a *ton* of these cases (at least, since I tend to vaguely follow `vim` questions which are on-the-fence, it feels like a lot to me), and I've seen many migrated and many *not* migrated.

I wouldn't vote to migrate that specific question because it sounds like the user wants to use PIL with the Xcode-provided Python.

I probably would have voted to migrate a similar question if the user had asked about *installing PIL as a prerequisite for some end-user application*.

It's a fine line as distinctions go, but [it could be much worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65693/157556).